# Missing IAPs - although IAPs are “Waiting For Review”

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

My App got rejected because of missing in app purchases although my products in iTunes as "Waiting for review" ,  Apple send provided information in Resolution center as:

> Missing IAPs
>
> Upon further review of your app, we are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review.
>
> Specifically, we noticed your have not submitted the subscription In App Purchases for review.

Can anyone suggest me how could i solve this issue thanks..

Comment: You might have not put the In App Purchase of your app in the waiting for review state. You have to select it from itunes connect while putting your app for waiting for review state.

Comment: Hi Manthan, My in app purchase products already in waiting for review

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below ScreenShot.

[image]

When you try to save all your data for the app submittion, then there is a "+" button on this page, Form where you need to select the InApp Product Ids for your apps if you have set up your In App correctly.

If all is good then it there will be your selected In Apps(Product Ids) shown here and then save your data.

Now when you put your app for submittion then your In App and your app both will be in waiting for review state.

**NOTE**

Your In App must be sumbitted at the same time when you submit your app.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Manthan, I did same and my app and in app products both both in waiting for review initially, After 10 days My app got rejected and products still in "Waiting for Review" and apple mentioned the issue as  Missing IAPs

Upon further review of your app, we are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review.

Comment: So the error mention that may be you would have forgot to put one of your in app purchase in waiting for review state. If you did that and still apple showed the error then contact apple support for that or submit the app again. Thanks...